# How to group by element in object of nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have nested arrays and objects. I want to filter out each medicine separately. Such as document:

```
{   
    person: "X",
    treatment: [
        {
            id: 1,
            medication: [
                {
                    name: "A"
                },
                {
                    name: "B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            medication: [
                {
                    name: "A"
                },
                {
                    name: "C"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    person: "Y",
    treatment: [
        {
            id: 1,
            medication: [
                {
                    name: "B"
                },
                {
                    name: "C"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I get a distinct list of top medication? Like this: A:2, B:2, C:2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) which outputs one document for each element in the array. As there are nested array's you'll need to apply `$unwind` twice.

E.g. for a collection named `medicine`:

```
db.medicine.aggregate([
  { 
    $unwind : "$treatment"
  },
  { 
    $unwind : "$treatment.medication"
  },
  {
    $group : { _id : "$treatment.medication.name", total: { $sum: 1 } }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $let: {
            vars: { data: [ { k: "$_id", v: "$total" } ] },
            in: "$$data"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "C" : 2 }
{ "B" : 2 }
{ "A" : 2 }
```

Note that when unwinding nested arrays, many documents can be generated if there are large arrays, so you might want to check this question [Consequences of using $unwind on nested arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693553/consequences-of-using-unwind-on-nested-arrays)

Comment: why you replaceRoot? and what is `$$data`?

Comment: Without $replaceRoot, you get an output which is correct, but not exactly like the one in your question.  { "_id" : "C", "total" : 2 } { "_id" : "B", "total" : 2 } { "_id" : "A", "total" : 2 }

Comment: `$arrayToObject` is transfer from array to object,  but with original root give an object, why?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't yet have a nice way to use a variable in a key. So instead we use a combination of $replaceRoot which promotes a specified document to the top level, and $arrayToObject which turns an array into an object. i.e. create an array with the desired key/value using $let and convert it to an object. It's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)